# removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, removeclass

Just a quick q regarding the jquery removeClass function.

I have a html list that goes as so:

```
 <li class="selected" id="s-12312">
 <li class="selected" id="s-12313">
 <li class="selected" id="s-12314">
```

and a javascript / jquery function to remove the class 'selected'

```
function test(id){
    $('li#s-' + id +'.selected').removeClass('selected')
}
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with me removing the class that the element is referenced from... or I've messed up the code :P

Thanks!

Comment: Should work, your id parameter is probably wrong, or that function is not being called at all.

Comment: Can you show how/when the function is called?

Comment: Why are you grabbing an element by it's `id` and also by it's `class`? Id's should be unique anyway?

Comment: What makes you think that it's not working?

Comment: What you have works. http://jsfiddle.net/cTBHH/

Comment: @MarkWalters I'm guessing they're thinking that's it's unnecessary to call `.removeClass()` on an element that doesn't have the class in the first place. But since it doesn't hurt to, they might as well not include the `.selected`

Comment: fiddled it myself.. works as expected... log out what you are passing as `id` and make sure it's what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

Here it is a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/7xbKj/

**HTML**

```
<li class="selected" id="s-12312" onclick="test('12312')">12312</li>
<li class="selected" id="s-12313" onclick="test('12313')">12313</li>
<li class="selected" id="s-12314" onclick="test('12314')">12314</li>
```

**JS**

```
window.test = function (id) {
    $('li#s-' + id +'.selected').removeClass('selected');
};
```

**CSS**

```
.selected {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why would this get a downvote?

Comment: I don't know. I was just trying to help with a live example with the provided code :\